# knitr: less/greater than sign displayed as (¡) and (¿)

Tags: r, knitr

I'm a beginner in using knitr to generate a report.
I have a R script (see below for an example; BTW I'm using RStudio for all of this) that runs without error and the output is a data frame. My rnw.file looks like this:

```
% !Rnw weave = knitr

\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\begin{document}

<<echo=FALSE,message=FALSE>>=
source("test.R")
kable(test.mat)
@

\end{document}
```

which displays the table quite nicely. The only problem I have is with the ">" (greater than) sign in the last column which is shown as "¿".

In found something about using

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

but this doesn't seem to do the trick here. Having included this, I can start compiling the script but after 10 minutes or so (and before it only took me some seconds to compile) I run into an error (exit code: 1).

Thanks in advance!

R.script (saved as "test.R"):

```
temp <- 12
test.mat <- as.data.frame(matrix(NA,ncol=2,nrow=1))
test.mat$V1 <- 2
test.mat$V2 <- paste(temp,"subjects > 28 days",sep=" ")
```

Comment: There may be a LaTeX solution that works better than the LaTeX intervention in the R code in @SabDeM 's answer. Consider posting on http://tex.stackexchange.com, with a link to here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't explain why it is working now, but here is what I found I should use in the preambel:

```
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

Found this in another [thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56956/problem-with-siunitx-and-t1-fontenc) (not really related to my question), but now I get what I want in the R output (no changes required in the R.script) as well as in the pdf.

Answer (score 0):

`>` is a mathematical symbol and as so it is not recognized unless it is not embedded in a a mathematical environment (inline or as a bloc.)
Try this code.

```
$>$
```

### A (not so elegant) solution

The behavior of `kable` remains strange. After I've analyzed the latex code that it produces I've tried this solution, which is not so elegant, but it works. Hoping that some other users will provide more efficient solutions. Here is my code.

```
% !Rnw weave = knitr
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}
<<echo = F, message = FALSE>>=
source("test.R")
aa1
@
\end{document}
```

where the `test.R` is:

```
temp <- 12
test.mat <- as.data.frame(matrix(NA,ncol=2,nrow=1))
test.mat$V1 <- 2
test.mat$V2 <- paste(temp,"subjects > 28 days",sep=" ")
aa <- kable(test.mat, format = "latex")
aa1 <- gsub(">", "$>$", aa)
```

and here is the result:
[image]

Comment: Thanks, but now I get " $¿$" in my pdf.
I can only do changes in the R.script because that's where the data.frame is created (which I then want to be displayed as a table in my pdf using the chunk above).

Comment: Very strange. Please show the initial part of your code that reproduce the error. My solution here should be work well already but it doesn't as you said.

Comment: In R, I'm creating a data.frame filled with NAs and then filling it step by step. In one field in the last column, there should be a character string like "XX subjects with > 28 days". Using this code in R:

    paste(X.X,"subjects with > 28 days",sep=" ")
it works fine in R, but if I source this script in a chunk in my rnw.file I get the "¿".

Comment: I am sorry, I did some experiments printing character strings with the `>` symbol and they are printed well. At this point I am stuck you have to provide a code that reproduces the error to figure the problem out.

Comment: Thanks, I provide some example code in my original post now.

Comment: so, `test.mat$V2 <- paste(temp,"subjects $>$ 28 days",sep=" ")` ?

Comment: @BenBolker I fear that it is not recognized well and rendered as `$?$`. There must be a problem but I can't understand where. It could be a but maybe.

Comment: @BenBolker the very strange things is that with your solution the code is exactly the same but the behavior is very different and in fact it does produce the error! even though I have no idea why!. I think that the matter is about of the "where" the kable is called.

Comment: Thank you, I'll go with that for now, but hope for a "more elegant" solution to get the right output in R AND in the pdf. ;-)